# Ignore an error that occurs in a redshift stored procedure

Tags: amazon-redshift

I need to ignore an error when running a procedure, but the error still seems to propagate. Is it possible to just swallow it somehow?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myproc()
AS $$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'bad_statement;';
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then

```
call myproc();
```

will result in:

> [2021-01-06 17:08:42] [42601][500310] Amazon Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "bad_statement";

Tested it in postgres and it ignores the error correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't think there is a way to do this. Amazon's documentation states

> In an Amazon Redshift stored procedure, the only supported handler_statement is RAISE. Any error encountered during the execution automatically ends the entire stored procedure call and rolls back the transaction. This occurs because subtransactions are not supported.

> If an error occurs in the exception handling block, it is propagated out and can be caught by an outer exception handling block, if one exists.

[stored-procedure-trapping-errors](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-trapping-errors.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can change your PROCEDURE from

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_employee_sp_2() AS
$$
```

to

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_employee_sp_2() NONATOMIC AS
$$
```

But It has a down side, It doesn't allow to use cursors or something. I can't use EXECUTE command to INSERT on a TABLE :/